# Request-URI Too Large Error - Get rid of GET?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, post, webrick

I have a form on my site where users can submit answer text to be checked by the controller.
It uses a standard GET form:

```
<%= form_tag('/submit', method: "get", remote: true) do %>
```

But I recently got the following error on long answer:

> Request-URI Too Large
>   WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge

Should I change the form to POST to fix the error? Would this require any other changes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on the browser / web server, but the average limit for a URL is 2000 characters.  So yes, if you are hitting the limit change it to POST.

This will require changing the form tag:

`<%= form_tag('/submit', method: "post", remote: true) do %>`

Depending on your current routing, it might also require updating your route: ( since when using `resources` POST requests by default are routed to the `create` method in your controller )

`match '/submit',  to: 'submit#index', via: :post`

Comment: If it still breaks when using "post" (did for me), then use a webserver other than "WebBrick" for development.  WebBrick imposes an arbitrary limit on post-request uri-size which can generate this error.

Comment: Changing to post if should be a get doesn't seem a good solution even if it works